# In tinkerpop gremlin, how do I search for Vertices where a property value is a subset of an argument?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I have a graph with Vertices that have a property "foo" that is a Set. I want to find all Vertices where "foo" is a subset of my input. For example,

```
g.addV('v').property('foo', 'bar').property('foo','baz')
```

I want to query this graph such that if given the input of `["bar, "quux", "quuz"]`, I will find no vertices that qualify because the Vertex property is not a subset of `["bar, "quux", "quuz"]`

If I were given input of `["bar", "quux, "quuz", "baz"]`, then this Vertex would be returned as `["bar", "baz"]` is a subset of `["bar", "quux, "quuz", "baz"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of set intersection is tricky as the Gremlin language does not have a `containsAll` type of method the way Groovy does. If you are able to include Groovy closures in your query (not all implementations allow them), one way to do it is as follows:

```java
gremlin> g.addV('v').property('foo', 'bar').property('foo','baz')
==>v[61286]  

gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('v').
......1>        filter {["bar", "quux", "quuz", "baz"].
......2>                containsAll(it.get().values('foo').
......3>                collect())}  
==>v[61286]  

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('v').property(set,'foo','abc')
==>v[61286]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('v').valueMap()
==>[foo:[bar,baz,abc]]

gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('v').
......1>        filter {["bar", "quux", "quuz", "baz"].
......2>                containsAll(it.get().values('foo').
......3>                collect())}  
gremlin>
```

In general use of closures is not recommended as not all implementations allow them and they are less likely to be able to take advantage of back end optimizations and indices.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. I do have access to the graph configuration so I could define closures there. Question: How would one pass arguments to closures from a client implementation (i.e NodeJS, Python)?

Comment: Here is the documentation for Python lambdas - the Node/Javascript examples are also in this same page https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python-lambda